# Kronecker product SVD Error bound

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, multilinear-algebra, svd, kronecker-product

The Kronecker Product SVD (KPSVD) is defined [here](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/ResearchPDF/KSVD.pdf). Given a target rank $r$, what is the error bound in terms of singular values $\sigma_i$ for $\|A - A_r\|_F$, where $A_r = \sum_{i=1}^r \sigma_iU_i \otimes V_i$?